# JMeter 5.5 Distributed org.apache.jmeter.engine.RemoteJMeterEngineImpl_Stub does not define or inherit an implementation

Tags: jmeter, distributed

Running JMeter 5.5 in distributed, master and slave mode, the following command replicates this error
Command

```
jmeter -f -Gup=3 -Gtime=1200 -Gthreads=15 -R10.104.60.246,10.104.60.7 -GData=source.csv -n -LERROR -t script.jmx -l result.csv -Djmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=csv
```

I apply the following configuration in Jmeter.properties on both master and slave

```
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Remote hosts and RMI configuration
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Remote Hosts - comma delimited
#remote_hosts=127.0.0.1
#remote_hosts=localhost:1099,localhost:2010

# RMI port to be used by the server (must start rmiregistry with same port)
server_port=1099

# To change the port to (say) 1234:
# On the server(s)
# - set server_port=1234
# - start rmiregistry with port 1234
# On Windows this can be done by:
# SET SERVER_PORT=1234
# JMETER-SERVER
#
# On Unix:
# SERVER_PORT=1234 jmeter-server
#
# On the client:
# - set remote_hosts=server:1234

# Parameter that controls the RMI port used by RemoteSampleListenerImpl (The Controller)
# Default value is 0 which means port is randomly assigned
# You may need to open Firewall port on the Controller machine
#client.rmi.localport=0

# When distributed test is starting, there may be several attempts to initialize
# remote engines. By default, only single try is made. Increase following property
# to make it retry for additional times
client.tries=6

# If there is initialization retries, following property sets delay between attempts
client.retries_delay=10000

# When all initialization tries was made, test will fail if some remote engines are failed
# Set following property to true to ignore failed nodes and proceed with test
client.continue_on_fail=true

# To change the default port (1099) used to access the server:
#server.rmi.port=1234

# To use a specific port for the JMeter server engine, define
# the following property before starting the server:
server.rmi.localport=1099

# The jmeter server creates by default the RMI registry as part of the server process.
# To stop the server creating the RMI registry:
#server.rmi.create=false

# Define the following property to cause JMeter to exit after the first test
#server.exitaftertest=true

#
# Configuration of Secure RMI connection
#
# Type of keystore : JKS
#server.rmi.ssl.keystore.type=JKS
#
# Keystore file that contains private key
#server.rmi.ssl.keystore.file=rmi_keystore.jks
#
# Password of Keystore
#server.rmi.ssl.keystore.password=changeit
#
# Key alias
#server.rmi.ssl.keystore.alias=rmi
#
# Type of truststore : JKS
#server.rmi.ssl.truststore.type=JKS
#
# Keystore file that contains certificate
#server.rmi.ssl.truststore.file=rmi_keystore.jks
#
# Password of Trust store
#server.rmi.ssl.truststore.password=changeit
#
# Set this if you don't want to use SSL for RMI
server.rmi.ssl.disable=true
```

console connection log

```
Creating summariser <summary>
2023-02-15T07:04:57.3003208Z Created the tree successfully using script.jmx
2023-02-15T07:04:57.3004130Z Configuring remote engine: 10.104.60.246
2023-02-15T07:04:57.3004748Z Using local port: 1099
2023-02-15T07:04:57.3006687Z Using remote object: UnicastRef2 [liveRef: [endpoint:[10.104.60.246:1099](remote),objID:[6bba637c:18653e2b059:-7fff, 9032198663335379476]]]
2023-02-15T07:04:57.3008029Z Configuring remote engine: 10.104.60.7
2023-02-15T07:04:57.3009445Z Using remote object: UnicastRef2 [liveRef: [endpoint:[10.104.60.7:1099](remote),objID:[-484801ae:18653e2a54f:-7fff, 3605628237727967827]]]
2023-02-15T07:04:57.3015525Z Starting distributed test with remote engines: [10.104.60.246, 10.104.60.7] @ 2023 Feb 15 02:04:43 COT (1676444683410)
2023-02-15T07:04:57.3018176Z An error occurred: Receiver class org.apache.jmeter.engine.RemoteJMeterEngineImpl_Stub does not define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method 'abstract void rsetProperties(java.util.HashMap)' of interface org.apache.jmeter.engine.RemoteJMeterEngine.
```

Configuration Machine
S.O: Amazon Linux 2
Java Versión: java-11-amazon-corretto.x86_64

Doing the same configuration in JMeter 5.0 works correctly

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to use JMeter 5.5 master with JMeter 5.0 slaves - it won't work, you need to have the same JMeter versions everywhere.

The same applies to [plugins](https://jmeter-plugins.org/), [dependency](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html) .jar files, [test data files](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config), etc. Master only passes the [.jmx test plan](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/JMETER/JmxTestPlan) to slaves, everything else needs to be installed and/or copied manually.

More information: [How to Perform Distributed Testing in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/distributed-testing-in-jmeter)